# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Tags: attributeerror

I'm trying to write a script that will write out to Google Docs Spreadsheet and when I run it I get the error in the title. More specifically:

```
File "/home/pi/Desktop/templog.py", line 44, in <module>
    s.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sched.py", line 117, in run
    action(*argument)
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/templog.py", line 35, in do_something
    entry = spr_client.InsertRow(data_str, spreadsheet_key, worksheet_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gdata/spreadsheet/service.py", line 330, in          InsertRow
for k, v in row_data.iteritems():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

The piece of code that is causing this is:

```
entry = spr_client.InsertRow(data_str, spreadsheet_key, worksheet_id)
        if isinstance(entry, gdata.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetsList):
```

Comment: I think `InsertRow` is expecting the first parameter to be a dictionary that maps values to column names, not a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the line causing the error is `row_data.iteritems()` because row_data is a string and the method you're calling is not defined for the class 'str'.

Comment: I've tried converting the "data_str" object to a string by using:

  `data_str=str(data)`

Where `data=commands.getoutput('pcsensor')` - which is just a date, time and sensor reading.